# Kafka Streams: TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm running a Kafka Streams application to consumer one topic with 20 partitions at traffic 15K records/sec. The application does a 1hr windowing and suppress the latest result per window. After running for sometime, it starts getting TimeoutException and then the instance is marked down by Kafka Streams.

Error trace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: 
task [2_7] Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record 
(key 372716656751 value InterimMessage [xxxxx..] 
timestamp 1566433307547) to topic XXXXX due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException:
Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
You can increase producer parameter `retries` and 
`retry.backoff.ms` to avoid this error.
```

I already increased the value of that two configs.

```
retries = 5
retry.backoff.ms = 80000
```

Should I increase them again as the error message mentioned? What should be a good value for these two values?

Comment: By any chance, do you use Kerberos authentication to connect?

Comment: @mazaneicha, no, I'm not using Kerberos.

Comment: @mazaneicha We use Kerberos and we face the same issue every time the cluster is bounced on the weekend. Do you know why?